# Authentication page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Im trying to build out my sign in page on a JavaScript, Node and Express app. Iv got the login correct, im getting a response when the users password and username match. So that part is fine. But once they match id like to take them to the home screen. However, im not sure how todo that. Iv found a `res.redirect("route")` but it returns: `res.redirect is not a function`. Ill add my code: ```app.post('/lgnfrm', function (req, res) {

```
var usrEmail= req.body.usrEmail;
var usrPassw = req.body.usrPass;

// INSERT WORKING
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM loginInfo WHERE email = (?)'
connection.query(sql, [usrEmail], function (err, res) {

  // IF/ELSE CHECKING IF PASSWORD AND EMAIL MATCH DB VALUES
  if (err) {
    //
    console.log(err)

  } else {
    // CHECKS IF THE EMAIL MATCHES DB
    console.log("VALID EMAIL")

    if (res.length > 0){

      // IF EMAIL VALID, CHECK PASSWORD
      if (res[0].passW == usrPassw) {

        res.redirect("/home");

        console.log("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");

      } else {
        // INCORRECT PASSWORD
        console.log("PASSWORD INCORRECT");
      }
    }
  }
})
```

}) ```

Comment: because you need to use the express instance response object not the sql response

Comment: Can you dive a little deeper into that? Not fully understanding.

Comment: somewhere in your code you have something like `app.get("/some-route", (req, res) { "you handle the request here})` you interchange this `res` with the other `res` that you provided in you code snippet.

Comment: Gotcha. But wouldnt I want todo that after the auth is successful?

Comment: yes of course, here I just showed what is the difference between the response object

Comment: The code that you provided is badly formatted, I could not see the `app.post` part

Comment: Im not seeing the code snipit

Comment: The app.post is in the code snipit. Can you give me an example of what your meaning?

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.post('/lgnfrm', function (request, response) {

  var usrEmail= request.body.usrEmail;
  var usrPassw = request.body.usrPass;

  // INSERT WORKING
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM loginInfo WHERE email = (?)'
  connection.query(sql, [usrEmail], function (err, res) {

    // IF/ELSE CHECKING IF PASSWORD AND EMAIL MATCH DB VALUES
    if (err) {
      //
      console.log(err)

    } else {
      // CHECKS IF THE EMAIL MATCHES DB
      console.log("VALID EMAIL")

      if (res.length > 0){

        // IF EMAIL VALID, CHECK PASSWORD
        if (res[0].passW == usrPassw) {

          response.redirect("/home");

          console.log("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");

        } else {
          // INCORRECT PASSWORD
          console.log("PASSWORD INCORRECT");
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```